# Operação matemática onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase

To tentando fazer uma operação matemática pegando um numero da child no firebase, mais sempre da erro de que não da pra converter string...
o `getCounter` esta como `String`no model , mais quando mudo ele pra int,long ou Double ele da o erro de que não da pra converter string...
Agradeço desde já.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) 
{

    final Blog blog = mQuestionList.get(position);
    int conta01 = Integer.parseInt(blog.getCounter());
    int conta02 = 5;
    int resultado = conta01-conta02;

    holder.new_post.setText(resultado);
```

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:327)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4663)
>                                                                                     at com.robertoc.meublogclash.AdapterRecyclerView.RecyclerViewAmigos.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAmigos.java:97)
>                                                                                     at com.robertoc.meublogclash.AdapterRecyclerView.RecyclerViewAmigos.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAmigos.java:32)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2730)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16715)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5482)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1981)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6245)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThrea
>   08-09 16:14:14.581 16981-16981/com.robertoc.meublogclash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está dando erro porque no método `setText`, se você passar um valor inteiro, ele entende que é prá pegar o valor de um resource com esse id (que provavelmente não vai existir, por isso o erro). Se quiser escrever o valor inteiro, tem que converter ele antes para String. Pode fazer dessa forma:

```
holder.new_post.setText("" + resultado);
```

Comment: valeu deu certo!